# Nhibernate delete object map and update database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a mcv project with nhibernate and i'm new at nhibernate.

On my moderator object i add Test column and update database with `SchemeUpdate`

```
new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(true, true);
```

Moderator Class:

```
 public class ModeratorMap : EntityBaseMap<Moderator>
    {
        public ModeratorMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Name);
            Map(x => x.LastLoginDate);
            Map(x => x.Mail);
            Map(x => x.Password);            
            Map(x => x.Test);   

            HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles).Table("ModeratorRoles").Cascade.All();
        }
    }
```

But if i try to delete Test mapping, (also i deleted on Moderator class) 
SchemeUpdate doesnt update database. 
SchemeExport.Drop works but i lose all my data on database.

Whats the solution for update ?

Answer (score 0):

SchemaUpdate has limited abilities and basically can only add missing tables and columns. Please consider using a full-featured migration frameworks, eg. [Fluent Migrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki).